# Php webservice calling from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I am trying to call a web-service which has a Json output from JavaScript. But I am unable to get the value. I tried with different methods but have been unsuccessful. Please help !!

Here is the code I tried

```
  <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

     function callajax(){ 
    var html =$.ajax({
       cache: false,
       type: "GET",
       async: false,`enter code here`
       data: {},
       url: "http://domain/abc.php?param=abcd',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       crossDomain: true,
       Success: SucceedFunc,`enter code here`
       error: function (request, errorText, errorCode) 
       {
         alert(errorText+"--"+errorCode);
       }
     });      
   }   
   function SucceedFunc(data, status) 
   {
    alert("Enter into Success");
    alert(data);
   }
```

Desired output is in {"name":Alex,"Success":true} format.
I need to pick value for "name".

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your `Success:` is capitalized? Should be `success:`.

EDIT:

Also, is there a reason you're using such an old version of jQuery? They're at 1.9.x now (for most uses). I just looked it up and the crossDomain option was added in 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ryan
I now tried with  
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
Even then I face the same problem.
I hope I am following the right way.